# Why are the items of my list not saving to JSON?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, file, tkinter

```
class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

        self.filepath = os.path.expanduser(r'~\Documents\joseDzirehChongToDoList\toDoListSaveFile.json')

        self.checkboxList = []

    def loadToJSON(self):
        with open (self.filepath, 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(self.checkboxList, outfile)

    def add(self, name):
        self.checkboxArea.add(name)
        self.checkboxList.append(name)
        self.loadToJSON()

def main():
    master = tk.Tk()
    master.title("To-Do List (with saving!)")
    master.geometry("300x300")
    win = MainWindow(master)
    win.pack(fill=tk.X)
    master.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The relevant function is `loadToJSON()`. It's supposed to load checkboxList into a file in `C:\Users\Josalina\Documents\joseDzirehChongToDoList` called `toDoListSaveFile.json`. Am I calling or defining `loadToJSON()` wrong? `MainWindow` does appear to have an attribute called `loadToJSON()`, so I think it's the calling that's getting me screwed up.

Comment: You should, please, read the help file about asking questions on SO. In the case of this question, the main thing to do would be to pare your code down to a few lines that demonstrate the difficulty you're experiencing.

Comment: @BillBell It's been trimmed

Comment: :) Trim more, much more. Typical we would like to read only about 15 lines or so.

Comment: @BillBell Even more trimmed :)

Comment: Try using `print` to display the values of `self.filepath` and `self.checkboxList` in `loadToJSON`.

Comment: @DavidCullen Ah, I see the issue now. Writing list items to the file works fine, but I'm not loading the items into self.checkboxList properly. Thanks!

Comment: Since I don't know what you did to fix the problem, you may have to answer your own question. Don't forget to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed. It was actually writing list items into the file just fine, but I forgot to load the items from the file to checkboxList. Then the next time `loadToJSON()` was called, it reset checkboxList.